# How to request a database schema via SQL query on popular SQL platforms?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

Is there a SQL query that returns the schema of the current database? Like with columns "table", "name", "type", etc.

The platforms in question are MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and T-SQL.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using (MSSQL, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: Database platform dependent.  Please specify

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that. Added the platforms.

Answer (score 2):

The real RDBMS should all support an [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) set of views and tables. I think SQLite has its own take on things, but then it's a SQL library rather than a full RDBMS.

If you stick to the ANSI standard stuff your queries should be portable enough, but obviously you won't get details of the various platform-specfic features.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` standard.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, try `SHOW TABLES;` and `DESCRIBE table_name;`

For more info, check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html